# Seeking cell mast data in UK

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I am looking for a shapefile containing the locations of cell masts that provide phone coverage in the UK. On sites like Orange, O2 etc they have an interactive signal checker (https://explore.ee.co.uk/coverage-checker for example), but I haven't found a way to obtain the data in GIS form. Have rung several phone companies, but the customer services down there don't seem to understand what I am asking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this [web site](http://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/handle/10672/372).

Answer (score 2):

Please check out in XLSX format http://www.ofcom.org.uk/static/sitefinder/Sitefinder-May-2012.zip